# Can you identify these antenna/items on the belly of a Cessna 172?

Tags: airframe, antenna

Not sure what all these antenna are for. I have my checkride soon and want to make sure I can name everything that might be pointed out. Thank you. [image]

[image]

Comment: You're wandering around a hangar. Why not find the aircraft's owner and ask them?

Comment: Why are you asking internet strangers about an airplane in which you are going to take a checkride? Ask your flight instructor. That is why you are paying them. If it is not the aircraft in which you are taking your checkride, the DPE is not going to ask you about it. And, a DPE is not going to ask you about items under the cowling on a PPL checkride (per your other question). If you are going for a checkride above PPL, you should not have to ask these questions. You should be able to do the research on your own (POH). If you don’t know your plane, you are not ready for a checkride

Comment: @Dean F. I have never seen antenna locations in a POH myself.  Wouldn't he need to look in a service manual?

Comment: @RyanMortensen - A service manual is a good call. The owner, CFI or A&P of that aircraft are an even better resources. Things might have been moved since 1977. Honestly, if he is going for a PPL or under checkride, the service manual may be beyond the scope of knowledge the DPE would expect. Since checking the antennae (visually and for looseness) is probably on the OPs preflight checklist, the CFI should have gone over which antennae those are in the first or second flight.

Comment: @DeanF. FYI. I did do my own research. I asked my CFI and A&P, as well as looked in the POH, but didn’t get a definitive answer, so I thought it would be helpful to ask internet strangers in case they have a wider scope of knowledge, but I was wrong. I guess this isn’t the kind of forum where people can ask questions. Why bother wasting everyone’s time asking me why I’m asking a question? I had a question so I asked it. I didn’t ask for negativity, but that’s all you had to offer a future pilot. And I was checkride ready, because I passed! BOOM! Thank you very much for your help. Not!

Comment: Congrats on the checkride, kid.